# How can I create a Taskbar Item for a running application at startup that isn't coupled to a specific window instance

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, taskbar

In applications like Skype, closing the window effectively minimizes to the taskbar on modern systems because notifications are shown directly on the taskbar overlay.  In my case, I have a multi-window ecosystem.  Is there a way to register some behavior assigned to a taskbar item that isn't part of the application lifecycle of a specific window?  Are there ways to do this in .NET? WPF specifically?

Ideally this would be for a situation where starting the application doesn't create a window handle, just a process etc.  Windows would be created contextually based on the usage.  Resources would load on demand.

Comment: If you are going to move to close at least leave a comment as to why.  I feel my question is pretty clear.  If you don't understand it, request more information.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about a Systray Icon, or rather about this kind of notification overlays associated with Systray tools. (Btw, today seems to be the day of the "-1". I have seen this quite often here at SO today. Somebody must have had a really terrible christmas eve...)

Comment: I never said system tray.  I said taskbar.  Think Skype,  if you 'close' the application, the item remains active in the taskbar to provide notifications. System tray is rarely useful.

Comment: Ah, okay. You can start an application without opening a Window. Just do not use the *StartupUri* property in your application's XAML (and override *Application.OnStartup* and OnStartup.OnExit, if necessary). You can actually do away with the XAML for your application object and just use the good old *main* method. If you intend to do some UI related stuff during the runtime of that program, you might also make sure the Application's Dispatcher object is initialized.

Comment: (contd.) I am not sure if in all cases i outlined a taskbar icon will appear, though. So you might need to experiment a bit... perhaps you would still need to create a Window handle for a taskbar icon to appear...

Comment: in WPF, you can't have a taskbar item without an associated VISIBLE window instance (not calling show, or explicitly setting visibility to anything other than visible hides the reference)

Comment: Also it's worth noting that dummy window instances (style none, 0% opacity etc.) still has a lot of undesired behaviors (such as issuing move or resize operations causing borders to be visible)

Comment: WPF is a no-go, as it does not provide you with a way to fiddle around with OS-specific things. I was looking into it a bit the last couple of minutes. It smells like you would need to create a native window, keep it hidden and intercept the relevant messages in the WindowProc. While WinForms has a NativeWindow type, from a quick glance it doesn't look to be flexible enough for that purpose. I currently think it is probably better to have a C++/CLR library that handles the WinAPI stuff. If i have some time tomorrow, i intend to create such a (fragmentary) library, but i can't promise.

Comment: Care to link the reference docs?

Comment: Do you mean WinAPI reference docs? Starting point should be the MSDN doc about [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From there, you can follow links regarding what is necessary to create a window, and how to setup a WindowProc. If you need more of an overview you could also google for something like "CreateWindowEx tutorial" (and find something like [this](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html), for example).

Comment: Regarding potential windows messages necessary to intercept, "[Window Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" might be a good entry point.

Comment: I was actually referring to the API to access and configure the TaskBar presence.  But it sounds like I'd be able to find it from there.  I'm considering just doing some pinvoke work from managed code.

Comment: Okay, if you go the P/Invoke route, you might look into the NativeWindow type. But you will do plenty of copy'n'paste of the Windows constants, and 'rebuild' the involved datastructures in C#/.NET. But if you not much experience working with C++ projects in VS, the efforts P/Invoke vs. learning C++/CLI are probably comparable.

Comment: Regarding manipulating (or rather changing) the taskbar icon, you might want to look at the [WM_SETICON message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and "[About icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)".